# Замыкание. На каком этапе происходит очистка lexical environment родительской функции?

Tags: javascript, функции, замыкания

```js
function makeCounter() { 
  let count = 0;
  return function() {
    return count++;
  }
}
let counter = makeCounter();
console.log(counter());
console.log(counter());
```

Мне непонятна эта фраза (цитатa с [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/closure#okruzhenie-v-detalyah)):

> Хотя функция `makeCounter()` закончила выполнение некоторое время назад, ее лексическое окружение остаётся в памяти, потому что есть вложенная функция с `[[Environment]]`, которая ссылается на нее.

**Как это происходит?**

При вызове функции в этой строке - `let counter = makeCounter();` функция `makeCounter` выполняется: создаёт переменную `count`, затем браузер заходит во внутреннюю функцию: сначала происходит поиск переменной `count` во внутреннем лексическом окружении, потом, когда браузер понимает, что тут этой переменной нет, переходит по ссылке в лексическое окружение родительской функции. Вложенная функция выполнилась, произошел ее возврат. Все ее лексическое окружение удалилось. Потом браузер вернулся к родительской функции - тоже закончил ее выполнение т.к. есть `return`. Лексическое окружение родительской функции удалилось.

Как лексическое окружение родительской функции может оставаться если вложенная функция на него больше не ссылается?

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что при вызове внешней функции `makeCounter();` также происходит _вызов_ вложенной функции?

Comment: вы из одной функции возвращаете другую. не вызываете а возвращаете. откуда и правда у вас эти цепочки логические, что возвращаемая функция также вызывается? вызывается она когда вы явно ее выполняете через `counter()`.

Comment: @wololo да, точно! а почему тогда при первом вызове вложенной функции - `counter` - в качестве результата возвращается 0? По идее же браузер должен зайти в эту вложенную функцию, увидеть переменную `count`, найти ее в родительской функции, а потом сразу же увеличить на единицу. Почему 0?

Comment: Особенность постфиксного инкремента. Он увеличивает значение переменной на единицу, но возвращает значение переменной до увеличения. Проверьте так: `let t = 0; console.log(t++); console.log(t);`.

Comment: @wololo А на каком этапе вложенная функция начинает ссылаться на лексическое окружение родительской функции? Во время ее вызова - `counter()`? Как такое может быть если лексическое окружение создается только при вызове функции, а не при ее объявлении - а на том этапе, на котором происходит вызов вложенной функции (`counter()`) родительская функция не выполняется, и лексического окружения у нее также уже нет.

Comment: У функций есть скрытое свойство `[[Environment]]`, которое ссылается на лексическое окружение в котором они были созданы и устанавливается один раз при создании функции. При вызове `makeCounter()` создаётся функция, и у неё устанавливается значение скрытого свойства `[[Environment]]`. Затем, каждый раз когда происходит вызов `counter()` создаётся новое лексическое окружение для этой функции, но в качестве ссылки на внешнее окружение берётся значение из `[[Environment]]`.

Comment: В общем, если кратко: 1) при создании функция запоминает в скрытом свойстве окружение, в котором была создана, 2) при каждом вызове функция создаёт себе новое лексическое окружение, но ссылку на внешнее окружение подсматривает в скрытом свойстве.

Comment: @wololo то есть получается, что окружение родительской функции (`makeCounter`) может быть доступно для ее вложенной функции (`counter`) в любое время? Я просто не понимаю как связать это воедино с тем, что лексическое окружение функции может существовать только во время ее выполнения. То есть я вызываю вложенную функцию, родительская функция в это время не выполняется, как у родительской функции (`makeCounter`) может оставаться лексическое окружение?

Comment: @wololo Если ещё упростить вопрос: "Как вложенная функция может обращаться к лексическому окружению родительской функции, если та не выполняется (а только при выполнении функции у нее существует лексическое окружение)?" На этом у меня затык... Почему лексическое окружение родительской функции не удаляется?

Comment: `Я просто не понимаю как связать это воедино с тем, что лексическое окружение функции может существовать только во время ее выполнения`. Так ведь это не так. Если есть ссылки на лексическое окружение, то оно продолжает жить даже после завершения работы функции. Лексическое окружение удаляется не при завершении работы функции, а когда оно больше не доступно.

Comment: @wololo а, то есть оно будет жить до тех пор, пока к нему кто-то "обращается" - грубо говоря, пока кто-то держит ссылку на это окружение. Хорошо, но родительская функция `makeCounter` завершила свое выполнение и ее лексическое окружение удалилось, потом оно как-то "восстанавливается", когда начинает выполняться вложенная функция `counter`? **На этом этапе же вложенная функция (`counter`) ещё не "обращалась" к окружению родительской функции, как она может УЖЕ держать ссылку на окружение своего "родителя"?**

Comment: `грубо говоря, пока кто-то держит ссылку на это окружение`. Да. `но родительская функция makeCounter завершила свое выполнение и ее лексическое окружение удалилось` Нет, т.к. есть ссылка, через которую можно получить доступ к этому окружению. У той функции, которую вернула `makeCounter` в скрытом свойстве `[[Environment]]` хранится ссылка на окружение `makeCounter`. Затем, эта функция `counter()` вызывается. У неё есть своё собственное окружение, но в качестве ссылки на родительское окружение берётся значение из свойства `[[Environment]]`.

Comment: Лексическое окружение — это объект. И функция — это тоже объект. (Это не в точности такие же объекты, какие получаются, когда вы пишите так: `someVar = {}`, но тем не менее объекты.) Здесь `return function() {return count++;}` возвращается объект-функция. И одно из его свойств — ссылка на объект-окружение функции `makeCounter`. До тех пор пока доступна функция `counter` — доступно и лексическое окружение функции `makeCounter`. Не напрямую, конечно же, опостредовано, через вызов `counter()`, но доступно.

Comment: Вы написали `let counter = makeCounter()`. Теперь в переменной `counter` хранится объект-функция. Одно из его скрытых свойств `[[Environment]]` ссылается на окружение функции `makeCounter`. Т.е. хоть `makeCounter` закончила работу, но окружение продолжает своё существование, т.к. на него есть ссылки. Теперь вызываем функцию `counter`: `counter()`. Здесь создаётся новое окружение, и в качестве его родителя берётся ссылка, хранящаяся в `[[Environment]]` объекта `counter`. Ещё раз: в `counter` хранится объект-функция, и одно из его свойств — ссылка на окружение в котором он(она) был(а) создан(а).

Comment: @wololo Ааа, я поняла что вы имеете в виду - не важно: выполнилась вложенная функция или нет, она всегда содержит и будет содержать ссылку на внешнюю родительскую функцию. Именно это и не позволяет лексическому окружению родительской функции удаляться. Получается, что новый вызов вложенной функции `counter` пользуется тем лексическим окружением родительской функции, 
которое было создано ещё при вызове функции `makeCounter`. Правильно, да?

Comment: да..............

Comment: @wololo большое спасибо за объяснение